# BufferedReader taking terminal enter character

Tags: java, input, bufferedreader

I am implementing socket programming in Java where I am using BufferedReader to get input from client. However, the BufferedReader object takes the newline character entered on console. 
Here is my server-side code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class FTPserver {

private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
private DataInputStream dis = null;
private DataOutputStream dos = null;

FTPserver() {
    try {
        String input;
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
        Socket socket = null;
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        input = dis.readUTF();
        if(input.equals("ftp")) {
            dos.writeUTF("ftp> ");
            input = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.print("opened connection to 10.10.10.212");
            dos.writeUTF("Connected to 10.10.10.212\n220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)\nName (10.10.10.212:root): ");
            input = dis.readUTF();
            dos.writeUTF("331 Please specify the password.\nPassword: ");
            input = dis.readUTF();
            dos.writeUTF("230 Login successful.\nRemote system type is UNIX\nUse binary mode to transfer files\nftp> ");
            input = dis.readUTF();       //receive mget
            dos.writeUTF("ftp> ");
            input = dis.readUTF();       //receive mput
            dos.writeUTF("ftp> ");
            //input = dis.readUTF();
            input = dis.readUTF();       //receive exit
            dos.writeUTF("Goodbye");
            input = dis.readUTF();       //receive exit
            dos.writeUTF("Goodbye");
        }
        dis.close();
        dos.close();
        socket.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FTPserver ftp = new FTPserver();
}
}
```

Here is my client code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class FTPclient {
private DataInputStream dis = null;
private DataOutputStream dos = null;
private Socket socket = null;

FTPclient() {
    try {
        String input,output;
        BufferedReader sc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        socket = new Socket("localhost",3000);
        dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        output = sc.readLine();
        dos.writeUTF(output);               // write ftp
        System.out.print(dis.readUTF());    // print ftp>
        dos.writeUTF(sc.readLine());            // write open 10.10.10.212
        System.out.print(dis.readUTF());    // print connected
        dos.writeUTF(sc.readLine());
        System.out.print(dis.readUTF());
        dos.writeUTF(sc.readLine());             //send mget
        System.out.print(dis.readUTF());

        dos.writeUTF(sc.readLine());             //send mput
        System.out.print(dis.readUTF());
        dos.writeUTF(sc.readLine());            //send exit
        System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
        dos.writeUTF(sc.readLine());             //send exit
        System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
        dis.close();
        dos.close();
        socket.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FTPclient ftp = new FTPclient();
}
}
```

Here is the input that I give on client console:

```
dell@dell-Inspiron-15-3567:~$ java FTPclient
ftp
ftp> open 10.10.10.212
Connected to 10.10.10.212
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (10.10.10.212:root): student
331 Please specify the password.
Password: student
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX
Use binary mode to transfer files
ftp> mget *.py
ftp> mput sample.java
ftp>                   //this line is getting skipped
exit
Goodbye
dell@dell-Inspiron-15-3567:~$
```

As mentioned in above console snippet, the line where user will enter `exit` is getting skipped. According an answer on stackoverflow, my input should end with  a terminating character. I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that by "skipped" you mean that the word 'exit' is being printed on the following line instead of directly after "ftp>" like in your previous lines.  If so, I think the reason that this is occurring is due to the fact that you are using System.out.println in these lines in your client instead of System.out.print as you are in the previous lines.  I think your input is terminating correctly as it appears that your program is ending correctly and not continuing to wait for further input.

```
    dos.writeUTF(sc.readLine());            //send exit
    System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
    dos.writeUTF(sc.readLine());             //send exit
    System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
```